# What would be the equivalent of this Python hash writting/accessing code on some lisp languages?

Tags: python, data-structures, clojure, lisp, scheme

What would be the equivalent of this Python code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.hp = 10
        self.pos = [0,0,0]
        self.items = []
    def damage(self,dmg):
        self.hp -= dmg

player = Player()
player.damage(3)
player.pos[0] += 5
player.items.append("banana")

print player.hp, player.pos, player.items
>> 3 [5,0,0] ["banana"]
```

In Clojure (or other Lisps)?

Comment: no, I just want to see how Lisp deal with this. I've tried: readed some chapters of Practical CL; it seemed overly complicated or I was getting if it was the same.  On Clojure I didn't understand what he was doing with the struct-map, and later on with the dispatch function thing. I'm not sure which of those (or other feature) would be used in this case, thus, why I'm asking.

Comment: @Matt removed it, doesn't apply.

Comment: Whoever voted down/close, care to explain?

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code   has small examples for pretty much any language while you wont find a 1 to 1 for your question it will probably show you the way

Comment: @JoranBeasley I knew this site but forgot! That will probably suffice. Thank you.

Comment: Benjamin I don't know many places besides Stack. What exactly is a mailing list? How would you find this place? Most of the forums I find by searching on Google are very inactive. Thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminCox Did you see Joran's post? You could try and be helpful... referencing the same link twice (really?)

Comment: If I could have, I would have down-voted this because you posted buggy code with inaccurate pretend output. This shows "lack of research effort". It is trivial to run something like this in Idle and copy-paste both the running code and actual output. The list append method is .append, not .push. With that corrected, the first number of the output is 13, because you add rather than subtract damage. With that corrected, the first number is 7 (10-3), as in Matt's post with real output, not 5.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistakes; I haven't tested the code as it is just a conceptual example and the numbers are not the point. I think you are missing the motivation of down-voting, though. There are many reasons for down-voting, such as it not being a real question. But lack of effort from the author (if this was the case) is not a good reason simply because the question can still help many people that have the same doubt. There are much more people consulting past answers than people asking new questions.

Comment: I've got great answers on this question. Thank you all.!

Comment: The Clojure mailing list is the first result from this google search, and is extremely active:  http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=clojure+mailing+list&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: @Jordan - we each have our preferences.  Perhaps I take the "How to Ask" page's admonitions about not posting until you've _tried_ something a little too seriously?

Comment: @Dokkat if you'd like to return the favor, it's easy - just accept one of the answers

Comment: @BenjaminCox , I always accept an answer after some time. This thread is awkward, though, as all answers provide part of what I asked.

Comment: "I always accept an answer"...   for some definition of "always", specifically 61% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure:

```
(def player {
    :hp 10
    :pos [0 0 0]
    :items [] })

(defn damage [player amount]
    (update-in player [:hp] - amount))

(defn move [player direction]
    (update-in player [:pos] #(map + % direction)))

(defn give [player item]
    (update-in player [:items] conj item))

(-> player
    (damage 3)
    (move [5 0 0])
    (give "banana"))

; Output: {:hp 7, :pos (5 0 0), :items ["banana"]}
```

Comment: Very simple, thank you! Could I write a macro for the (assoc player :attr (conj (player :attr) item))

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `update-in` which I think is more idiomatic in this case and also alleviates the need for macros. But of course one could write a macro to shorten things up even more. (But in this case I don't think it's necessary and could even hurt readability)

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure, you wouldn't normally use a mutable data structure, you'd instead create an immutable piece of data that describes the player's current state. Updates to the player would create a new piece of data that describes the updated state. Matt's answer gives a good example of doing this.

If you wanted to maintain a single "player" identity over time with multiple changes of state, you could do so with an atom, something like this:

```
(def initial-player-state 
 {:hp 10
  :pos [0 0 0]
  :items []})

(def player (atom initial-player-state))

;; Define some update functions

(defn damage [player dmg]
  (update-in player [:hp] + dmg))

(defn move [player dir]
  (update-in player [:pos] #(vec (map + % dir))))

(defn add-item [player item]
  (update-in player [:items] conj item))

;;  Make some changes

(swap! player move [5 0 0])
(swap! player damage -3)
(swap! player add-item "Apple")

;; view the current player state by dereferencing the atom

@player
=> {:hp 10, :pos [0 0 0], :items ["Apple"]}
```

Note that in a real game, you might have the entire immutable game state in a single atom, not just the player.

Comment: And thank you, great answer. I'm getting the atom concept now.

Comment: @ just gets the current value (state) of the atom, i.e. the player hashmap. if you just do `player`you will get the atom itself, rather than the atom's contents....

Answer (score 3):

In [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org):

```
#lang racket

(define player%
  (class object%
    (init-field [hp 10] [pos '(0 0 0)] [items '()])

    (define/public (damage dmg)
      (set! hp (- hp dmg)))

    (define/public (move dx dy dz)
      (set! pos (list (+ (first pos) dx)
                      (+ (second pos) dy)
                      (+ (third pos) dz))))

    (define/public (add-item item)
      (set! items (cons item items)))

    (super-new)))

(send* (new player%)
       (damage 3)
       (move 5 0 0)
       (add-item "banana"))
```

You might want to program in a more functional style if you're using Racket, in which case you can write the methods like this to avoid mutation:

```
(define/public (damage dmg)
  (new this% [hp (- hp dmg)] [pos pos] [items items]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I accidentally downvoted your answer. Stack Overflow is not allowing me to change it: http://i.imgur.com/X2U1x.png

Comment: @Dokkat, I edited the answer just to let you fix your accidental down-vote.  (All I did was add an extra blank line at the end.)

Answer (score 3):

In Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defclass player ()
  ((hp :accessor hp :initform 10)
   (pos :accessor pos :initform (list 0 0 0))
   (items :accessor items :initform nil)))

(defmethod damage ((a-player player) damage)
  (decf (hp a-player) damage))
```

In the REPL

```lisp
; compiling (DEFCLASS PLAYER ...)
; compiling (DEFMETHOD DAMAGE ...)
CL-USER> (defparameter *player* (make-instance 'player))

*PLAYER*
CL-USER> (damage *player* 3)
7
CL-USER> (incf (car (pos *player*)) 5)
5
CL-USER> (push :banana (items *player*))
(:BANANA)
CL-USER> (list (hp *player*) (pos *player*) (items *player*))
(7 (5 0 0) (:BANANA))
CL-USER>
```

Personally, I'd break `pos` up into separate `x`, `y` and `z`, and probably define some methods to put things into and out of the inventory, just in case I decide to change the representation later.

Comment: I'd possibly express the position as (vector 0 0 0) and closely investigate if I have a single list that is shared or get new lists for each invocation. I'd possibly go as far as leaving the initial value as nil and create a player-creating function.